# Merge 2 cache entries into one

Tags: django, caching, redis

There are invoices that I am caching but with 2 cache entry. First cache entry holds if caching of the invoices are existing or not. Why I am doing it? Because there is a business logic (get_cache_timeout method) that tells me when to update 2nd cache entry which is holding the actual invoice details.
So, first one is a flag for me to understand if 2nd cache entry is there or not. If not, I call the backend system and update 1st and 2nd cache entry.

The reason behind of having 2nd cache key with 60 days is that, for the worst case if 1st entry doesn't exist and then call to the backend system fails, I want to still return 2nd cache entry as a response instead of showing error.

```
cache.set(f'{invoices}_cache_exists', True, get_cache_timeout())
cache.set(f'{invoices}_cache', some_cache, 60*60*24*60)
```

Sorry for confusing explanation but I hope you get the idea behind of this solution.

So, in the end my question is that for this problem how can I get rid of 1st cache entry and only having 2nd cache entry with 2 timeouts? 1st one is giving me telling when to update, and 2nd one is to remove the cache.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
#cache.set(f'{invoices}_cache_exists', True, get_cache_timeout())
cache.set(f'{invoices}_cache', some_cache, get_cache_timeout())
```

you can make your cache expires in `get_cache_timeout()` time.

In the end, if the cache entry expires it needs to be updated so knowing `when to update` is solved.

On the order hand, `when to remove`, well, it will be removed every `get_cache_timeout()` seconds/minutes.

**It just not make sense to have a cache entry with a TTL of `M` min that has to be updated every `m` min where M > n**

Comment: that's already there but think about this scenario.
get_cache_timeout returns 30 days, and after 30 days I call my API and my API depends on another API. however that API doesn't respond so I can't serve the data from cache and also can't set new cache.
however, in that kind of scenario I just want to serve the cache which needs to be on Redis for 60 days, because even the latest invoice is not there it's better than serving some data to the user than serving nothing.

Comment: Your problem sounds like you need to import the data from that another API to your databases. If the other API does not respond fallback to your database, if the API does respond, update cache and your database data.